# \rowcolor not working in latex IEEEtrans

Tags: tables, color, multirow, ieeetran, colortbl

I am trying to colour rows in some tables in a latex IEEEtran article but the colouring **does not show at all**, and no error is thrown as well.
Here is the snippet of code I used:

```
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcellgapes{4pt}%parameter for the spacing
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
            \begin{table*}[t]
             \centering
             \caption{Some of the previous DBQ studies in the literature} \label{tab:Studies}
             \begin{tabular}{lccl}
               &&&\\
               \rowcolor{gray!20}
               \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Country}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{DBQ type}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Year published}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Resulting factors}}\\
                \rowcolor{gray!20}
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{*}{UK\cite{parker1995}}& \multirow{3}{*}{....} & \multirow{3}{*}{1995} & driving under influence \\
                &&& driving while texting\\
                \bottomrule
             \end{tabular}
            \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- package `mdwtab` is not compatible with the package `colortbl`, consequently with it row colors not show up
- ieee journals doesn't allows colored tables
- your table code is unnecessary complicated. do you really need all this `multirows` and table over two columns? with example of table, which you provide it can be easily fit in one column.
- if you persist with colored row with column headers than a possible mwe (mnimal working example) can be:

  ```
  \documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
  \usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
      \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
      \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
      \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
      \addparagraphcolumntypes{R}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}

  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

  \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[66]
      \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{Some of the previous DBQ studies in the literature} \label{tab:Studies}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l c c S{R}}
  \rowcolor{gray!20}
  \textbf{Country}
      & \textbf{DBQ type} & \textbf{Year published} & \textbf{Resulting factors}  \\
  %
  UK\cite{parker1995}
      &                   & 1995                      & driving under influence   \\
  ...
      & ...               & ...                       & driving while texting     \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table}
  \lipsum[1-5]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

- above table is simple to extend to `table*`
- if cell contents in your table is bigger, please provide three rows of table which emulate your real table.

Comment: Thank you for all your hard work! I will take everything in mind.
Kudos